# ARP cache MAC and Docker

Tags: networking, docker, mac-address, arp, google-cloud-platform

When I run `cat /proc/net/arp` I see two entries* bound to :

```
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
35.224.99.156    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        docker0
35.222.85.5      0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        docker0
```

Even after `ip -s -s neigh flush all` and  `arp -n` these entries come back. What do the results above mean?

Why is the ARP binding the docker0 device to an IPs (35.224.99.156) and (35.222.85.5) with mac `00:00:00:00:00:00` which I do not recognise all though they are from Google Cloud/Google or spoofed to be as such.

Is this expected, a bug or corruption or something more sinister?

*detected originally using OSQuery

```
SELECT address, mac, COUNT(mac) AS mac_count
  FROM arp_cache GROUP BY mac
  HAVING count(mac) > 1;
```

`docker network inspect bridge` is

```
[
   {
       "Name": "bridge",
       "Id": "REDACTED",
       "Created": "2019-02-09T17:38:43.817882245Z",
       "Scope": "local",
       "Driver": "bridge",
       "EnableIPv6": false,
       "IPAM": {
           "Driver": "default",
           "Options": null,
           "Config": [
               {
                   "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                   "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
               }
           ]
       },
       "Internal": false,
       "Attachable": false,
       "Ingress": false,
       "ConfigFrom": {
           "Network": ""
       },
       "ConfigOnly": false,
       "Containers": {},
       "Options": {
           "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
           "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
           "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
           "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
           "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
           "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
       },
       "Labels": {}
   }
]
```

Comment: Include the `docker network inspect bridge` output.

Comment: @BMitch post updated with output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are from connectivity-checks made by NetworkManager.

```
# nslookup connectivity-check.ubuntu.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   connectivity-check.ubuntu.com
Address: 35.224.99.156
Name:   connectivity-check.ubuntu.com
Address: 35.222.85.5
```

There is a bug so the arp-request go out the wrong interfaces. See: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1634286

You can prevent this by removing the package *network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu*

```
apt purge network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu
```